# Error while installing Plone

Tags: permissions, proxy, wget

I was installing Plone on my laptop, and got this error.

```
Plone-5.0.6-UnifiedInstaller-r1.tgz: Permission denied
Cannot write to ‘Plone-5.0.6-UnifiedInstaller-r1.tgz’ (Success).
```

I don't know what this means. I work with a proxy and I did add proxy and password with `wget` as shown below.

```
wget --proxy-user "user" --proxy-password "password" --no-check-certificate https://launchpad.net/plone/5.0/5.0.6/+download/Plone-5.0.6-UnifiedInstaller-r1.tgz
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?